# How can I make dir(obj) return non-function members in swig generated python classes?

Tags: python, swig

I'm using swig to generate python wrapper for a C++ library.
I tend to use the generated python module in an interactive manner using ipython.

Say I have the following C++ class:

```
class test
{
    int num;
    int foo();
};
```

Swig wraps this class with a python class:

```
class test:
    def foo():...
    __swig_getmethods__["num"] = ...
    __swig_setmethods__["num"] = ...
    .
    .
    .
```

When using interactively with ipython. I have noticed that tab completions will successfully find "foo", but not "num".

After a little digging, I saw that ipython uses the "dir" method for tab completion.
The way swig generates non-function class members is by implementing `__setattr__` and `__getattr__`. All they do is check the `__swig_set/getmethods__` dictionaries and return the value, if found.
This is why members like "num" are not returned when trying `dir(test)`.

Ideally, it would be nice if swig could implement `__dir__`, for each of its classes. Something like this could be added to every swig wrapper class:

```
# Merge the two method dictionaries, and get the keys
__swig_dir__ = dict(__swig_getmethods__.items() + __swig_setmethods__.items()).keys()
# Implement __dir__() to return it plus all of the other members
def __dir__(self):
    return __dict__.keys() + __swig_dir__
```

My questions:

1. Is there an easy way to get the dir() function to return the non-function members as well?
2. If the answer to 1 is no, is there an easy way to add the above code in every python class that swig generates?

I know this is a minor thing, but tab completion has a very positive effect on productivity in my opinion.

Thanks

Comment: This might be better asked on the mailing list. You might get the most positive response if you code a quick hack to add the members to the `__dict__`, test it out, then post it.

Comment: I guess you're right. I'll try to do that. In the meantime though, I was hoping for a possible workaround. Some method for inserting the above code to every generated python class. Maybe I'll ask that in a separate question. Thanks.

Comment: It's not that this question is bad, but rather that SO is sometimes not the perfect place for certain questions, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPython wraps dir in a new function dir2 inside IPython/core/completer.py

So you could try to redefine dir2. Something like:

```
import IPython.core.completer
old_dir = IPython.core.completer.dir2

def my_dir(obj):
    methods = old_dir(obj)
    #merge your swig methods in
    return methods

IPython.core.completer.dir2 = my_dir
```

Comment: That I already know...This code is already present in my question. My question is, how do I make swig put this code inside every generated python class.

Comment: Ah my apologies. I must have misunderstood the priorities in your two questions.

Comment: Actually, after reviewing your answer again, it seems like I'm the one who misunderstood, so my apologies... You meant that I should override the global dir() function, instead of the per class __dir__() function, right? While not the perfect solution, that's actually a very good idea for a workaround. I'll try it out. Thanks!

Comment: Trying it out in ipython though, it doesn't work. Although the dir function now shows the other members, the tab completion in ipython still doesn't. It only works if I implement dir within the class. Thanks nonetheless. Still is a good idea :)

Comment: I have rewritten the suggestion to modify the dir2 function inside the IPython interpreter.

Comment: Well, it's a little hackier than I hoped for, but it does work. Can't argue with that. It might be worthwhile to wrap this code with a try/catch, in case ipython is not installed. Mind if I add that to your answer? Thanks!